Why two asserts can pass? C++ memory model on x86
Why in the following program on x86 two asserts can pass? (from the point of view of the c++/rust memory model, I understand why this is possible)
x = false
y = false

Thread1:
x = true  // release

Thread2:
y = true  // release

Thread3:
assert(x && !y)  // acquire

Thread4:
assert(!x && y)  // acquire

In theory, caches are coherent and if such an assertion assert(x && !y) passed on a core, then the core that wrote x == true dropped the store buffer and all cores should see the changes, including the core on which the assertion assert(!x && y) will be executed.

If x,y are not atomic (or protected in any other way) you have a race condition and thus UB.

C++ doesn't care about the underlying hardware.  If you have a shared variable and one or more threads writes to the variable then you must have synchronization.  If not then you have a data race which is UB.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior - in case you didn't read this yet. UB can be surprising and doesn't need to "make sense".

Even if the hardware could assign booleans in an atomic way..  the virtual machine of C++ says it is undefined behavior

You should mention the types of x and y. You already mention acquire and release, so are they atomic<bool> or regular bool-s?

Was the question reverted intentionally?

I made an edit to make explicit that these are atomic objects. I think the author clearly intended this, since otherwise saying "acquire" and "release" makes no sense.  Someone else rolled it back, so I won't insist, but OP is welcome to roll back to my version if it's what they meant.

I know that the edit would "invalidate" the current answer, but I think that answer was a misinterpretation from the start.

@NateEldredge Lets let the OP make that decision.

As I understand it, the question is asking what kind of compiler optimizations and/or hardware behavior (consistent with the x86 architecture) could lead to the stated behavior actually being observed.  It's a question about implementations, not just about the abstract language.  So tags such as [tag:compiler-optimization] and [tag:cpu-architecture] might help clarify that the question is looking for something deeper than "it's undefined / unspecified by the ISO standard".

"from the point of view of the c++/rust memory model, I understand why this is possible": If that is the case, then I do not really know what your question is. Aren't you saying that you already know and understand the answer?

If you compile in release mode your asserts are likely removed, so they would of course pass. Hopefully not your issue, but you didn't specify. (we now have 3 Nates in the comments)

Per [intro.races]:

Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location ([intro.memory]) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

and

The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

In a nutshell, since you are not (apparently) performing any synchronization between your threads, you have a data race, which is UB.

Edit:
As Nate Eldredge pointed out, you may have intended that x and y were of type std::atomic_bool and your code was more like:
std::atomic_bool x{false};
std::atomic_bool y{false};

// Thread1:
x.store(true, std::memory_order_release);

// Thread2:
y.store(true, std::memory_order_release);

// Thread3:
assert(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) && !y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))

// Thread4:
assert(!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) && y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))

In which case my answer changes a little bit. You still have a race condition, just no undefined behavior. Your race is between the the atomic loads and the atomic stores, which have no "ordered before" guarantees in the way the code is written; you will need some thread synchronization mechanism to guarantee your desired oredering of reads happening after writes.

With the comments "acquire" and "release", I'm assuming OP means these are std::atomic objects and the loads and stores are being performed with the relevant memory ordering.  So we're thinking of std::atomic<bool> x{false}, y{false}; and x = true  // release is shorthand for x.store(true, std::memory_order_release), etc.  If so then there is no data race and no UB, but still the results of the loads are unspecified.

@NateEldredge Thanks for chiming in. That's a great take., and you're probably right about what OP meant. Hopefully they clarify the types and actual operations being performed, because otherwise an interpretation of x = false could just as well mean auto x = false which will give a simple bool typing.

I think you're missing the point. The OP doesn't require both asserts to pass on every execution, they're asking how it's possible that they can both pass on some executions.  (I think this looks like an IRIW litmus test, so the can't on x86; IRIW reordering is disallowed even on paper, same on ARMv8.  It's only possible in practice on some POWER chips, and NVidia GPUs.)  Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?)

@PeterCordes I didn't think I missed that at all. The asserts happen in separate threads and their load operations are not ordered with respect to the store operations (each of which are also in separate threads). It's a race condition.

Your answer suggests adding synchronization to rule out some possible orderings.  That doesn't explain anything about how it could be possible for both asserts to succeed on the same execution of the litmus test.  (Which again isn't possible on x86.)

@PeterCordes it is absolutely possible for both asserts to succeed without any thread synchronization. X and y both begin as false. And then two threads independently set x and y while two other threads make the asserts. None of the four threads' operations are ordered with respect to each other. I do however assume that the initial values of x and y are set in a main thread prior to the four threads' creations.

Oh right, this isn't an IRIW litmus test since both readers read x then y.  Both can pass even with seq_cst, just with different interleavings of program-order of the readers and writers.  Your answer should explain that, and/or show an ordering that's consistent with the sequencing of && and the acquire loads.  (y is written after x, and both loads in Thread 3 run between those.  Thread 4's load of x runs before either store, its load of y runs after both.)  We're talking about x86 with its total-store-order memory model, so it's meaningful to say y is stored before x.
